# In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames warning when sorting data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have tried two methods to sort a data frame by column values:

```
dateCol = "DATE"
df <- data.frame( DATE = c("01-10-2020","01-04-2020","01-06-2020","01-02-2020"),
                  VAL = c(3,7,4,5))

# Method 1
df <- df[order(df[dateCol]),] 

# Method 2
df <- df[order(df[which(colnames(df)==dateCol)]),]
```

and they both trigger the same warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
2: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Your main issue is you need `\`[[\`` instead of `\`[\``. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/6574038 This wasn't covered yet by the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some alternatives. All use `fmt` defined in (1).

**1) Base R** The date format is ambiguous but choose one of the `fmt` values below.  Then pick ou8t the desired column, convert it to Date class, find the indexes which would sort it and then apply them.

```
# choose one of the following
fmt <- "%d-%m-%Y"
fmt <- "%m-%d-%Y"

df2 <- df  # in case we need to preserve input
df2[[dateCol]] <- as.Date(df2[[dateCol]], fmt)
o <- order(df2[[dateCol]])
df2[o, ]
##         DATE VAL
## 4 2020-01-02   5
## 2 2020-01-04   7
## 3 2020-01-06   4
## 1 2020-01-10   3
```

**2) zoo** Another possibility is to convert it to a zoo object and then possibly back.  The conversion automatically sorts it and converts it to Date class.  If a zoo object is ok as a result then omit the last line.

```
library(zoo)
VAL <- read.zoo(df, index = dateCol, format = fmt)
fortify.zoo(VAL, name = dateCol)
##         DATE VAL
## 1 2020-01-02   5
## 2 2020-01-04   7
## 3 2020-01-06   4
## 4 2020-01-10   3
```

**3) dplyr** We can convert the dates and then use arrange to sort.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(!!dateCol:=as.Date(.[[dateCol]], fmt)) %>%
  arrange(.[[dateCol]])
##         DATE VAL
## 1 2020-01-02   5
## 2 2020-01-04   7
## 3 2020-01-06   4
## 4 2020-01-10   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing `[dateCol]` you need to write `[,dateCol]` to specify that `dateCol` is the name of a column.
These pieces of code work to me:

`df <- df[order(df[,dateCol]),]`

`df <- df[order(df[,which(colnames(df)==dateCol)]),]`

I hope this answer can help you.